# Convert MysqlData to JSON

Tags: php

Hi I am creating an android app and made a fetch API that can get the converted json data

Here's my code

`lib.php`

```
public function fetchUserData($username)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                $userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;   
                }
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

and on my `fetch_api.php`

```
<?php

require_once '../database/database.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    
    // edittext from android
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $arr = array();

    if($user->fetchUserData($username))
    {
        $arr['success'] = 1;
        $arr['message'] = "Success fetching data";
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    else
    {
        $arr['success'] = 0;
        $arr['message'] = "Failed fetching data";
        echo json_encode($arr); 
    }
}

?>
```

Right now I can successfully get the

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Success fetching data"
}
```

Now I want to display all of my data like `fullname`, `address`, `phonenumber` etc to be displayed .

When I am trying to do it like this

`lib.php`

```
public function fetchUserData($username)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                $userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($userRows)
                {
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "User Profile";
                    $response["user"] = array();

                    foreach($userRows as $rows)
                    {
                        $user = array();
                        $user["username"] = $rows['username'];
                        $user["fullname"] = $rows['fullname'];

                        array_push($response["user"], $user);
                    }
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                else
                {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Failed Fetching";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

It's giving me the error saying

> illegal string offset warning on username and fullname

I hope I am clear on my problem . Please ask me if my question is not clear so I can edit my question . Thank you.

### ADDED

when I directly use `json_encode` like this

```
public function fetchUserData($username)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                $userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                json_encode($userRows);
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

it gives me this result

> {"success":0,"message":"Failed fetching data"}

Comment: Where does `$userRows` get set?

Comment: no need to put `$userRows` under a foreach. the information you want is inside it already, just simply encode it

Comment: should i just directly `json_encode($userRows);` ??

Comment: @Paula you can json_encode it directly

Comment: @FlashThunder if I do `json_encode($userRows);` directly it gives me the `{"success":0,"message":"Failed fetching data"}`

Comment: you are mixing some code then and what you have posted is not the full story

Comment: Added info @FlashThunder

Comment: ok wait... and what does `fetch_api.php` has to do with it, because the result that you are getting is `$arr` from `fetch_api.php`

Comment: You should be returning the user data from `fetchUserData()` - you currently return true or false, so when you added the `json_encode()` it was then not returning anything.

Comment: change this line `json_encode($userRows);` to this line `echo json_encode($userRows);` in the code you have added and it will echo the json

Comment: @FlashThunder, the idea of echoing data in functions like this can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @NigelRen for testing purposes, to see if query is ok

Comment: Ok I think I know what is the problem of Paula. I will write my answer...

Comment: okay so when i `echo json_encode($userRows)` it displays my data but i am still getting tho this `{"success":0,"message":"Failed
fetching data"}`

Comment: @FlashThunder okay I will wait for the answer . Thank you for taking the time . Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the problem that you are facing is how to return rows from the class methods, when it should only return true on success and false on fail.

You got something like that:

```
<?php
    class user{
    
        ...
    
        public function fetchUserData($username)
            {
                try
                {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
                $userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;   
                }
                
                }
                catch(PDOException $ex)
                {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
            }
        
        ...
    
        }
?>
```

You need to add a public property like `$userRows` to it and assign that property with your method:

```
class user{   
    public $userRows; // added here

    ...

    public function fetchUserData($username)
        {
            try
            {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
            $this->userRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // changed here
```

And after that you can:

```
<?php

    ...

    if($user->fetchUserData($username)){
        echo json_encode($user->userRows);
    }else{
        echo "error occured";
    }
```

Hopefully it helped.

Comment: yeah I corrected it, was a typo in the last chunk of code, should be `$user->userRows` not `$user->userRow`